# Junit: How to run tests from project using command line

Tags: java, junit, junit4

this is the build structure of the classes in the project

```
(root project)
    |__ build
            |__ classes
                     |__ main/org/loklak/harvester
                                               |__ abc.class
                     |__ test/org/loklak/harvester
                                               |__ abc_test.class
                                               |__ def_test.class
```

I built the project using **gradle** and **junit 4.12** , and builds properly
I have checked that abc_test.class exists at above location,
but When I run ->

```
java -Xmx1024m -classpath build/libs/loklak_server-all.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore org.loklak.harvester.abc_test
```

I get error ->

```
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.004
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [org.loklak.harvester.abc_test]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.loklak.harvester.abc_test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
    ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

where as this command works fine ->

```
java -Xmx1024m -classpath build/libs/loklak_server-all.jar org.loklak.harvester.abc
```

**abc_test.java**

```
package org.loklak.harvester;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;
import org.loklak.harvester.abc;

public class abc_test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(def_test.class);

        for (Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {
           System.out.println(failure.toString());
        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());
   }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the error, What i am missing in java commandline command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your naming is really confusing. Class names go UpperCase in java; you do NOT use _ within them. And note: you talk about `abc_test` in your code; but the exception says `test_harvester` - a name that doesn't show anywhere else in your input!

Beyond that, I *guess* the answer here is: you need **three** parts in the classpath when running JUnit:

- JUnit itself
- your production classes
- your test classes

I am guessing: your **test** classes are **not** in that JAR that you give to java for your JUnit run. Probably because gradle doesn't add the test classes into your JAR by default (which makes sense: why would you want to ship your unit test classes to your customers?!)

Comment: So do I have to add test directory in /build/classes in the classpath ?

Comment: You have to make sure, that the class files compiled from your test classes are in the classpath when you trigger the JUnit run. How you get them there, I am not sure (in the sense of: I don't know how to do that in a "gradle" manner). Of course, you could step back, and do everything manually, and then just include the corresponding directory - just to see if my assumption about your problem is correct.

Comment: yep, thank you, this solved the problem :-) . Including the build/classes/test directory worked.